# i+1 inside rails hash code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to generate `map_blue_1.png`, `map_blue_2.png`, etc. with the following code but some coding error on the `{i+1}`. What is the proper way?

```
<% content_for :in_script do %>
    $("#map").gMap({ 
        markers: [
                  <% @spots.each_with_index do |spot, i| %>
                    <% if spot.geocoded? %>
                    {
                      latitude: <%= spot.lat %>,
                      longitude: <%= spot.lng %>,
                      html: "<a href='#item_<%= i + 1 %>'><strong><%=h spot.name %></strong></a>",
                      icon: { image: "<%= APP_CONFIG[:site_url] + '/images/map_blue_' + {i+1} + '.png' %>",
                              iconsize: [48, 48],
                              iconanchor: [24,48],
                              infowindowanchor: [24, 0] }
                    },
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                 ],
        zoom: 12 });
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`APP_CONFIG[:site_url] + '/images/map_blue_' + (i+1).to_s + '.png'`

or

`"#{APP_CONFIG[:site_url]}/images/map_blue_#{i+1}.png"`

Comment: For what it's worth, the second approach, ie using the #{} sections, is seen as best practise as it's more robust, because it always converts everything to strings automatically.  If you routinely use the first approach, of adding strings together, you're going to forget to use to_s sometime and it's going to blow up when it tries to add a number or nil to a string.

Comment: agree, I'd rather use the second one. Thanks Max